# How to divide a cell array element by a number

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array which is : A(1x2) .

I want to take the determinant of it and divide it by a number.

```
 W={[4,-2;-2,0.2],[4,-2;-2,0.2]}
```

Can I take the determinant of W?  And How can I divide it by a number?

If i use `cell2mat()` it will convert it to a matrix , but it will not be a
symmetric matrix. 
  the complete code is:

```
 W={[4,-2;-2,0.2],[4,-2;-2,0.2]};
 N=size(W,1);

 S = cell(1,numel(W));  %% initialize S first
 nu = 9;     % don't assign constants inside the loop
 Arg=[nu-N+1:nu];  % don't assign constants inside the loop
 for i = 1: numel(W)
 S{i}=W{i}/nu;  %% no parens here
 K=2^(nu*N/2)*pi^(N*(N-1)/4)*prod(gamma(Arg/2));
 Wd = 1/K * (det(S{i})^(-nu/2) * (det(W{i})^((nu-N-1)/2) * exp(-1/2* trace(inv(S{i})*W{i}));  %% removed lots of parens, added some curly braces
```

end

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: try this: `cellfun(@det,A)`

Comment: What output do you expect? The question is unclear to me.

Comment: @ daniel , i put the function , still  receiving  error  :(

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your assignment isn't quite valid MATLAB, so let's change it to:

```
W={[4,-2;-2,0.2],[4,-2;-2,0.2]};
```

That creates a valid cell array in MATLAB.  It had two elements, each of which is a 2x2 matrix.  To get at the elements to take the determinant, you have to *dereference* them, like so:

```
det1 = det(W{1})
det2 = det(W{2})
```

Note the curly braces.  If you used regular MATLAB indexing, like so:

```
det1 = det(A(1))  %% DOESN'T WORK
```

you would get an error, because det() doesn't work on cell arrays.  The dereferencing curly braces are needed to remove the outer layer (the cell array) and get at the inner layer (the matrix).

To divide by a number, you just do normal division:

```
det1 = det1 / my_number;
```

and of course, you could have done it all in one statement:

```
det1 = det(A{1}) / my_number;
```

EDIT: to divide a matrix by a number, just divide!

```
new_W = W{1}/num
```

EDIT2: your code disappeared, but I retrieved it from you edit history, and I think the main problem is just getting your dereferences correct.  Here is a corrected version:

```
 W={[4,-2;-2,0.2],[4,-2;-2,0.2]};
 N=size(W,1);

 S = cell(1, numel(W));  %% initialize S first
 nu = 9;     % don't assign constants inside the loop
 Arg=[nu-N+1:nu];  % don't assign constants inside the loop
 for i = 1: numel(W)
     S{i}=W{i}/nu;  %% no parens here
     K=2^(nu*N/2)*pi^(N*(N-1)/4)*prod(gamma(Arg/2));
     Wd = 1/K * (det(S{i})^(-nu/2) * (det(W{i})^((nu-N-1)/2) * exp(      -1/2*trace(inv(S{i}*W{i}));  %% removed lots of parens, added some curly braces
 end
```

Comment: I tried the det () its work , but  i am facing another issue which is :  S=W{1}/my number  ?  its not work :(

Comment: the standard division operator should work (see modified answer) unless I misunderstand you question.  If that isn't work, please post the exact code you are using, and we can debug it for you.

Comment: @shawinkarim: I don't think `N=size(W,1)` is doing what you want.  If you want the number of matrices in W, you probably want to use `numel()` or `length()`, or change to `N=size(W,2)` if you will always build W the same way.  You are building a cell array W with one row and many columns, but `N=size(W,1)` is going to count the number of rows, which will always be 1 in this example.

Comment: Wd = 1/K * (det(S{i})^(-nu/2) * (det(W{i})^((nu-N-1)/2) * exp(      -1/2*trace(inv(S{i}*W{i}));  %% removed lots of parens, added some curly braces%%      
                                                                has problem again :(

Comment: ok solve it , but the result is   0.000000000000000 +   0.027588845080168i    what is this plus ??                                                                             0.000000000000000 + 0.027588845080168i    ????  i should have one value ??

Comment: it's not two values, it's an imaginary number.  When you do `det(S{1})^(-nu/2)`, you are taking a square root of a negative number, so you will get an imaginary value.  MATLAB uses `i = sqrt(-1)` to denote the imaginary unit.

Comment: @– gariepy  : if i use    N=size(W,1);  i will have 
 -11.875985997688764,and if N=size(W,2); i will get the imaginary number ??

Comment: @shawinkarim: In the first case, N=1, and in the second case N=2, and they will give different answers.  I don't know exactly what equations you are trying to implement, but if N is supposed to be the number of matrices, then N should be 2.  If you aren't expecting an imaginary number for an answer, then make sure you have all your parentheses in the right places when you calculate Wd.

Comment: i still have problem : i update the function  and code the inverse is just for S :(